# How do I add new lines to a custom SharePoint workflow activity sentence

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am building a custom workflow activity in a fully-trusted solution for SharePoint 2010. The activity has several configurable parameters, which causes the RuleDesigner sentence to grow somewhat long-ish. For whatever reason, SharePoint Designer 2010 does not automatically wrap the words if the sentence, so I wind up with a wide activity and a horizontal scroll bar.

I am interested in either wrapping the words, or adding newline characters within the sentence; however, I have not been successful so far. Here is what I have tried:

### C-style newlines:

```
  <RuleDesigner Sentence="Line1\n    Line2\n    Line3.">
      ...
  </RuleDesigner>
```

### XML Attribute-encoded newlines

```
  <RuleDesigner Sentence="Line1&#xA;    Line2&#xA;    Line3">
      ...
  </RuleDesigner>
```

### Literal newlines:

```
  <RuleDesigner Sentence="Line1
Line2
Line3">
      ...
  </RuleDesigner>
```

The effects of these three approaches are all the same; that is, the new line is ignored and the sentence still appears as a single line of text in SPD.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this, or am I out of luck?